# Error handling of user input in a List<int>

Tags: c#, list, oop, error-handling

I have the following code:

```
       List<int> moneys = new List<int>();
       Console.WriteLine("Please enter the cost of your choice");
       int money = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       moneys.Add(money);
```

From this if you enter text then the program stops working and an Unhandled exception message appears. I was wondering how you would handle the exception, if it is even possible so that the program doesn't stop working?

Comment: Rather than handling the exception with Try/Catch, use TryParse instead of Parse and check the return value to see if the parse succeeded.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method. it will not throw an exception if input is not valid. do this

```
int money;
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out money))
   moneys.Add(money);
```

Comment: +1 this for me is the most complete/concise answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
int money ;
bool pass = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out money);
if(pass)
       moneys.Add(money);
```

Comment: I would assume `TryParse` does the exception handing under the hood so there's no real need to implement your own `try...catch` here.

Comment: @James I don't get you. I showed him 2 alternatives. `TryParse` or `Parse` to give a complete answer.

Comment: It is possible that TryParse calls Parse under the hood or uses some validation. I don't know, and I don't really care tbh. But both can be useful depending on the developer.

Comment: my point is the second part to your question is unnecessary. It's like saying "*here's the recommended way of doing what you need and here's another way that does it 3x longer and not recommended*". The second part is effectively using exceptions to control program flow which isn't really a good idea. According to @Servy `TryParse` doesn't even throw an exception under the hood so even more reason to use it.

Comment: "3x longer and not recommended" is subjective. If it is an exceptional case then throwing an exception might be better, and if speed is not an issue.

Comment: For this type of scenario an exception is overkill - all the OP is doing is validating an input field.

Comment: @James For this scenario, yes. But if a future scenario occurs that does warrant it then the OP obviously having no idea of try catch blocks (seems that way to me) creates a new question. Anyway, this  argument is also overkill ;)

Comment: If you don't think it is relevant you are free to edit it away

Comment: What argument? I only made a simple comment about the `try...catch` being unnecessary when you already have a recommended/built-in way of doing what the OP asks. Your answer isn't technically wrong but *IMO* I wouldn't advise it. I prefer not to edit other people's answers, plus there is already a more concise answer in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a [`try-catch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) block or use [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To handle the exception after it is thrown, use a try/catch block.

```
try
{
//input
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//try again
}
```

You can also handle it beforehand by using TryParse, and checking if int is null.

Comment: It's not really considered good practise to handle `Exception` you could end up swallowing other exceptions which aren't specific to what you are trying to do.

Comment: You also shouldn't use exceptions for control flow.

Answer (score 0):

`int.Parse` is ment to throw an exception when it fails to parse the string. You have 2 choices:

1) Use Try/Catch to handle the exception

```
try {
    int money = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    moneys.Add(money);
} catch {
    //Did not parse, do something
}
```

This option allows more flexibility in dealing with different type of errors. You can extend the catch block to split the 3 possible mistakes in the input string and another default catch block to handle other errors:

```
} catch (ArgumentNullException e) {
    //The Console.ReadLine() returned Null
} catch (FormatException e) {
    //The input did not match a valid number format
} catch (OverflowException e) {
    //The input exceded the maximum value of a Int
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Other unexpected exception (Mostlikely unrelated to the parsing itself)
}
```

2) Use `int.TryParse` which returns `true` or `false` depending on wether the string was parsed or not and sends the result into the variable specified in the 2nd paramater (with the `out`keyword)

```
int money;
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out money))
    moneys.Add(money);
else
    //Did not parse, do something
```

Comment: It isn't wise to assume the only exception that code be thrown in that code block is down to the input format, best to be more specific and catch `FormatException`. With that being said, I am pretty sure `TryParse` does this under the hood anyway so best sticking with that.

Comment: It does when it starts to mask other problems.

Comment: As long as all the information is there, it doesn't mask problem. It helps understanding. See updated answer.

Comment: @James `TryParse` doesn't catch an exception, it avoids throwing an exception to begin with, which is why it's often preferable.

Comment: @servy even better! I wasn't sure what it did under the hood (I just assumed it did that).

Comment: @Servy But thats just a situational choice. I leave the choice to the OP. Perhaps he wants to know if the string was not parsed because the number was too high, and wants to show a different messages to the user.

Comment: @Pluc That's a pretty unusual requirement; generally it's best to not assume requirements like that exist unless you're told they exist, especially when changing the code accordingly is quite straightforward.  And as I commented on another answer, you shouldn't be using exceptions for normal control flow, at least not unless there is a compelling reason, which here there isn't.

Comment: @Servy Why is that unusual? Expecially when it's a user input behing parsed. If it's a back-end calculation, I would definitly use it. But in the OP's case, the input is a console written string that could definitly surpassing the MaxValue of a Int, and the user would just feel the software is broken and does not accept his value. I think that showing both ways pros and cons is better then blindly giving an answer with no explaination. I also do not see why handled exceptions are a bad thing.

Comment: @Pluc It's unusual in that the vast majority of the time I'm in this situation (which is fairly often) there is no need to differentiate between invalid because of a non-numeric character and invalid because the number is too large.  Generally just "invalid" is enough for at least most cases, to the point that I wouldn't assume otherwise unless specifically told.  As for why you shouldn't use exceptions for control flow, the two main reasons are semantics and performance. Using exceptions are expensive, and additionally exceptions should be reserved for truly exceptional cases, hence the name.

Comment: @Servy Using exceptions are expensive? That's not what banchmarks tells us... Where did you get this information? And as for "semantics", well, thats really, really opinion based. I'm leaving the full answer because I personally had to differentiate the cause of parsing failure in a few projects before and that according to multiple online ressources, there is next to no performance hit using exceptions and I personally disagree with the semantics reasoning.

Comment: @Pluc exceptions are expensive if they are used exhaustively throughout an application...and if you are using them for scenarios like this I can only assume you are doing just that. The real issue here is your perception of what you deem *exceptional* - validating a free-form entry **is not** an exceptional circumstance in my opinion. Something like attempting to open a file or find a record in the DB which *should* exist but doesn't is more of an exceptional circumstance - reason being the application is no longer in a valid state because a resource it depends on is not accessible.